# Import options.options from option and import models couldn't be resolved

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have a .py file named train_esrgan_WV which is a part of RS-ESRGAN github repository (if you'd like to check the repo: https://github.com/luissalgueiro/rs-esrgan). I am training my dataset for super-resolution implementation. I keep getting errors in the .py file after the end of training. In this file, some modules could not be resolved and underlined with yellow color as seen in the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv98T.png)
This is the whole .py file I mentioned:

```
import os.path
import sys
import math
import argparse
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
import logging
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import options.options as option
from utils import util
from data import create_dataloader, create_dataset
from models import create_model

### Imports luis
import earthpy as et
import geopandas as gpd
import earthpy.plot as ep
import cv2

import os


def main():
    idxx= 0

    # options
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-opt', type=str, required=True, help='Path to option JSON file.')
    opt = option.parse(parser.parse_args().opt, is_train=True)
    opt = option.dict_to_nonedict(opt)  # Convert to NoneDict, which return None for missing key.
    ratio = opt["scale"]


    print("DATASET items", opt['datasets'].items)
    PreUp = opt["datasets"]["train"]["PreUP"]
    LR_down = opt["datasets"]["train"]["LR_down"]
    standa = opt["datasets"]["train"]["stand"]


    if PreUp == True:
        ratio=5

    # train from scratch OR resume training
    if opt['path']['resume_state']:  # resuming training
        resume_state = torch.load(opt['path']['resume_state'])
    else:  # training from scratch
        resume_state = None
        util.mkdir_and_rename(opt['path']['experiments_root'])  # rename old folder if exists
        util.mkdirs((path for key, path in opt['path'].items() if not key == 'experiments_root'
                     and 'pretrain_model' not in key and 'resume' not in key))

    # config loggers. Before it, the log will not work
    util.setup_logger(None, opt['path']['log'], 'train', level=logging.INFO, screen=True)
    util.setup_logger('val', opt['path']['log'], 'val', level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger('base')

    if resume_state:
        logger.info('Resuming training from epoch: {}, iter: {}.'.format(
            resume_state['epoch'], resume_state['iter']))
        option.check_resume(opt)  # check resume options

    logger.info(option.dict2str(opt))
    # tensorboard logger
    if opt['use_tb_logger'] and 'debug' not in opt['name']:
        from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
        tb_logger_train = SummaryWriter(log_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR_2020/tb_logger/' + opt['name'] + "/train")
        tb_logger_val = SummaryWriter(log_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR_2020/tb_logger/' + opt['name'] + "/val" )


    # random seed
    seed = opt['train']['manual_seed']
    if seed is None:
        seed = 100  #random.randint(1, 10000)
    logger.info('Random seed: {}'.format(seed))
    util.set_random_seed(seed)

    torch.backends.cudnn.benckmark = True
    # torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

# #########################################
# ######## DATA LOADER ####################
# #########################################
    # create train and val dataloader
    for phase, dataset_opt in opt['datasets'].items():
        if phase == 'train':
            print("Entro DATASET train......")
            train_set = create_dataset(dataset_opt)
            print("CREO DATASET train_set ", train_set)

            train_size = int(math.ceil(len(train_set) / dataset_opt['batch_size']))
            logger.info('Number of train images: {:,d}, iters: {:,d}'.format(
                len(train_set), train_size))
            total_iters = int(opt['train']['niter'])
            total_epochs = int(math.ceil(total_iters / train_size))
            logger.info('Total epochs needed: {:d} for iters {:,d}'.format(
                total_epochs, total_iters))
            train_loader = create_dataloader(train_set, dataset_opt)
            print("CREO train loader: ", train_loader)
        elif phase == 'val':
            print("Entro en phase VAL....")
            val_set = create_dataset(dataset_opt)
            val_loader = create_dataloader(val_set, dataset_opt)
            logger.info('Number of val images in [{:s}]: {:d}'.format(dataset_opt['name'],
                                                                      len(val_set)))
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('Phase [{:s}] is not recognized.'.format(phase))
    assert train_loader is not None
    assert val_loader is not None

    # create model
    model = create_model(opt)

    # resume training
    if resume_state:
        print("RESUMING state")
        start_epoch = resume_state['epoch']
        current_step = resume_state['iter']
        model.resume_training(resume_state)  # handle optimizers and schedulers
    else:
        current_step = 0
        start_epoch = 0
        print("PASO.....   INIT ")

    # #########################################
    # #########    training    ################
    # #########################################
    # ii=0
    logger.info('Start training from epoch: {:d}, iter: {:d}'.format(start_epoch, current_step))
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, total_epochs):
        for _, train_data in enumerate(train_loader):

            current_step += 1
            if current_step > total_iters:
                break
            # update learning rate
            model.update_learning_rate()

            # training
            model.feed_data(train_data)
            model.optimize_parameters(current_step)

            # log train
            if current_step % opt['logger']['print_freq'] == 0:
                logs = model.get_current_log()
                message = '<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}, lr:{:.3e}> '.format(
                    epoch, current_step, model.get_current_learning_rate())
                for k, v in logs.items():
                    message += '{:s}: {:.4e} '.format(k, v)
                    # tensorboard logger
                    if opt['use_tb_logger'] and 'debug' not in opt['name']:
                        if "test" in k:
                            tb_logger_val.add_scalar(k, v, current_step)
                        else:
                            tb_logger_train.add_scalar(k, v, current_step)
                logger.info(message)

            if current_step % opt['train']['val_freq'] == 0:
                avg_psnr_sr, avg_psnr_lr, avg_psnr_dif  = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
                avg_ssim_lr, avg_ssim_sr, avg_ssim_dif    = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
                avg_ergas_lr, avg_ergas_sr, avg_ergas_dif = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
                idx = 0
                freqpass =0.0
                if idxx==0:
                    best_psnr, best_ssim, best_ergas = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
                    idxx=1


                for _, val_data in enumerate(val_loader):
                    idx += 1
                    img_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(val_data['LR_path'][0]))[0]
                    img_dir = os.path.join(opt['path']['val_images'], img_name)
                    # print("*****Img nameVaL: ", img_name)
                    model.feed_data(val_data)
                    model.test()

                    visuals = model.get_current_visuals()
                    freqpass=0

                    if standa == True:
                        # print("UTIL_STANDA")
                        sr_img = util.tensor2imgStand(visuals['SR'], MeanVal = val_data["LR_mean"], StdVal = val_data["LR_std"])  # uint16
                        gt_img = util.tensor2imgStand(visuals['HR'], MeanVal = val_data["HR_mean"], StdVal = val_data["HR_std"])  # uint16
                        lr_img = util.tensor2imgStand(visuals['LR'], MeanVal = val_data["LR_mean"], StdVal = val_data["LR_std"])  # uint16
                    else:
                        # print("******UTIL_NORM**********")
                        sr_img = util.tensor2imgNorm(visuals['SR'],out_type=np.uint8, min_max=(0, 1),
                        MinVal=val_data["LR_min"], MaxVal=val_data["LR_max"], freqpass=val_data["lowpass_lr"]   )  # uint16
                        
                        gt_img = util.tensor2imgNorm(visuals['HR'],out_type=np.uint8, min_max=(0, 1),
                         MinVal=val_data["HR_min"], MaxVal=val_data["HR_max"], freqpass=val_data["lowpass_hr"] )  # uint16
                        
                        lr_img = util.tensor2imgNorm(visuals['LR'], out_type=np.uint8, min_max=(0, 1),
                                                 MinVal=val_data["LR_min"], MaxVal=val_data["LR_max"],
                                                 freqpass=val_data["lowpass_lr"])  # uint16

                    if LR_down==True or PreUp==False:
                        dim2 = (gt_img.shape[1], gt_img.shape[1])
                        lr_img = cv2.resize(np.transpose(lr_img,(1,2,0)), dim2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
                        lr_img = np.transpose(lr_img,(2,0,1))


                    # Save SR images for reference
                    if idx < 10:
                        util.mkdir(img_dir)
                        save_img_path = os.path.join(img_dir, '{:s}_{:d}'.format(img_name, current_step))
                        # print("SAVING CROPS PREUP", PreUp )
                        util.save_imgCROP(lr_img,gt_img,sr_img , save_img_path, ratio, PreUp=PreUp)


                    avg_psnr_sr += util.calculate_psnr2(sr_img, gt_img)
                    avg_psnr_lr += util.calculate_psnr2(lr_img, gt_img)
                    avg_ssim_lr += util.calculate_ssim2(lr_img, gt_img)
                    avg_ssim_sr += util.calculate_ssim2(sr_img, gt_img)
                    avg_ergas_lr += util.calculate_ergas(lr_img, gt_img, pixratio=ratio)
                    avg_ergas_sr += util.calculate_ergas(sr_img, gt_img, pixratio=ratio)


                avg_psnr_sr = avg_psnr_sr / idx
                avg_psnr_lr = avg_psnr_lr / idx
                avg_psnr_dif = avg_psnr_lr - avg_psnr_sr
                avg_ssim_lr = avg_ssim_lr / idx
                avg_ssim_sr = avg_ssim_sr / idx
                avg_ssim_dif = avg_ssim_lr - avg_ssim_sr
                avg_ergas_lr  = avg_ergas_lr / idx
                avg_ergas_sr  = avg_ergas_sr / idx
                avg_ergas_dif = avg_ergas_lr - avg_ergas_sr

                # log VALIDATION
                logger.info('# Validation # PSNR: {:.4e}'.format(avg_psnr_sr))
                logger.info('# Validation # SSIM: {:.4e}'.format(avg_ssim_sr))
                logger.info('# Validation # ERGAS: {:.4e}'.format(avg_ergas_sr))

                logger_val = logging.getLogger('val')  # validation logger
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> psnr_SR: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_psnr_sr))
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> psnr_LR: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_psnr_lr))
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> psnr_DIF: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_psnr_dif))

                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> ssim_LR: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_ssim_lr))
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> ssim_SR: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_ssim_sr))
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> ssim_DIF: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_ssim_dif))

                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> ergas_LR: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_ergas_lr))
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> ergas_SR: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_ergas_sr))
                logger_val.info('<epoch:{:3d}, iter:{:8,d}> ergas_DIF: {:.4e}'.format(
                    epoch, current_step, avg_ergas_dif))

                # tensorboarqd logger
                # if opt['use_tb_logger'] and 'debug' not in opt['name']:
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('dif_PSNR', avg_psnr_dif, current_step)
                #     # tb_logger.add_scalar('psnr', avg_psnr, current_step)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('dif_SSIM', avg_ssim_dif, current_step)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('dif_ERGAS', avg_ergas_dif, current_step)

                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('psnr_LR', avg_psnr_lr, current_step)
                #     # tb_logger.add_scalar('psnr', avg_psnr, current_step)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('ssim_LR', avg_ssim_lr, current_step)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('ERGAS_LR', avg_ergas_lr, current_step)

                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('psnr_SR', avg_psnr_sr, current_step)
                #     # tb_logger.add_scalar('psnr', avg_psnr, current_step)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('ssim_SR', avg_ssim_sr, current_step)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_scalar('ERGAS_SR', avg_ergas_sr, current_step)

                #     fig1= ep.plot_rgb(sr_img, rgb=[2, 1, 0], stretch=True)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_figure("SR_plt", fig1, current_step,close=True)
                #     fig2 = ep.plot_rgb(gt_img, rgb=[2, 1, 0], stretch=True)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_figure("GT_plt", fig2, current_step, close=True)
                #     fig3 = ep.plot_rgb(lr_img, rgb=[2, 1, 0], stretch=True)
                #     tb_logger_val.add_figure("LR_plt", fig3, current_step, close=True)
                #     # print("TERMINO GUARDAR IMG TB")


            if current_step % opt['logger']['save_checkpoint_freq'] == 0:
                logger.info('Saving models and training states.')
                print("Current step: ", current_step)
                model.save(current_step)
                model.save_training_state(epoch, current_step)
    logger.info('Saving the final model.')
    model.save('latest')
    logger.info('End of training.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Most probably, my errors stem from the importing problem of these modules.

I did a research in google but I could not find any answer related to importing options.options and models with pip like (pip install ...). How can I import them? By the way, I am working in google colab environment. This is my colab script to make the training work:

```
!pip3 install pandas
!pip3 install scikit-image
!pip3 install matplotlib
!pip install torch

import pandas
import matplotlib
import math
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio

!pip install torchvision
!pip3 install opencv-python
!git clone https://github.com/luissalgueiro/rs-esrgan.git

# Loading a JSON File to a Python Dictionary
import json

with open('/content/rs-esrgan/options/train/train_ESRGAN_WV_5x_ALL.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)

import json

# Data to be written
dictionary = {'name': 'P41_ESRGAN_ALL_L1_x5_PREUP_FT_StanData', 'use_tb_logger': True, 'model': 'srragan', 'scale': 5, 'gpu_ids': [0], 'datasets': {'train': {'name': 'GDAL', 'mode': 'LRHR', 'data_IDs': '/content/dataset/bandas_all.csv', 'dataroot_HR': '/content/dataset/train_HR', 'dataroot_LR': '/content/dataset/train_LR', 'subset_file': None, 'use_shuffle': True, 'n_workers': 1, 'batch_size': 2, 'HR_size': 140, 'use_flip': True, 'use_rot': True, 'stand': True, 'LR_down': False, 'PreUP': True, 'norm': False, 'up_lr': False, 'HF': False, 'scale': 5}, 'val': {'name': 'val_GDAL', 'mode': 'LRHR', 'data_IDs': '/content/dataset/valid.csv', 'dataroot_HR': '/content/dataset/valid_HR', 'dataroot_LR': '/content/dataset/valid_LR', 'HR_size': 140, 'stand': True, 'norm': False, 'LR_down': False, 'PreUP': True, 'up_lr': False, 'HF': False, 'scale': 5}}, 'path': {'root': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR', 'work_root': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR_2020/', 'resume_state': None}, 'network_G': {'which_model_G': 'RRDB_net', 'norm_type': None, 'mode': 'CNA', 'nf': 64, 'nb': 23, 'in_nc': 3, 'out_nc': 3}, 'network_D': {'which_model_D': 'discriminator_vgg_128', 'norm_type': None, 'act_type': 'leakyrelu', 'mode': 'CNA', 'nf': 64, 'in_nc': 3}, 'train': {'lr_G': 0.0001, 'weight_decay_G': 0, 'beta1_G': 0.9, 'lr_D': 0.0001, 'weight_decay_D': 0, 'beta1_D': 0.9, 'lr_scheme': 'MultiStepLR', 'lr_steps': [20000, 40000, 60000, 80000], 'lr_gamma': 0.5, 'pixel_criterion': 'l1', 'pixel_weight': 0.01, 'feature_criterion': 'l1', 'feature_weight': 1, 'gan_type': 'vanilla', 'gan_weight': 0.005, 'manual_seed': 100, 'niter': 101000, 'val_freq': 10000}, 'logger': {'print_freq': 100, 'save_checkpoint_freq': 10000}}
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)
# Writing to sample.json
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)
!python /content/rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py -opt /content/sample.json
```

Comment: `"options"` and `"models"` are packages provided in that git repo (folders). Is your script in the root of that project?

Comment: Yes, my script is in the repo along with options and models folders. I cloned the repo with git clone .

Comment: hmm, when I do so, those imports seem fine. The only ones I see complaints about are those under ### Imports luis as I have not installed any of those packages.

Comment: they were also underlined with yellow lines but I installed them one by one with !pip install in google colab and the lines disappeared.

Comment: Did you check the script in google colab? Neither python 3.10 nor python 3.6 change the situation :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the solution by importing the folders inside my main github folder to usr/local/lib/Python3.10/dist-packages in google colab. After starting the session again, local packages are imported.